# Getting Brilliantretail and Freeform Pro to play nice

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, brilliantretail

So I was forwarded here by Solspace since this is apparently their "paid" support now for Freeform Pro users :P

c&p of my questions I posed to them:
I recently ran across a project that requires me to make an order form. I'm currently using BrilliantRetail for the storefront, and then a special member groups gets to expedite things using an order form as apposed to going through a standard checkout process.

I have this, somewhat, working with Freeform Pro and am hoping to get a little more help to finish things up.

What I'm doing now is populating the form with channel entries (really br_products, but it works the same). Each product has an qty option associated with it, which is simply a text field in the Freeform form. Now, I'm sort of getting the data I need, but not the details.

So I have a field named qty, then each product produces a tag like this:

```
<input id="qty" type="number" name="qty[]" value="" />
```

So the quantity gets passed along but I also needed the Title, SKU, and Price. So I added three hidden fields for this, and added this to my template:

```
<input id="title" type="hidden" name="title[]" value="{title}" />
<input id="sku" type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="{sku}" />
<input id="price" type="hidden" name="price[]" value="{price}" />
```

So this also works, but I'm getting product info for products not ordered (because all the hidden fields are now filled in they all get returned, not what I want). What I need to do is only see the "title", "sku", and "price" for products that actually have "qty" filled in. This is my problem, I don't know how to do this??

My idea was using data-attributes for the "qty" input, so the data is attached to the product being ordered, but I don't know how to do this??

Hoping someone here can help me figure this out! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I, sort of, answered my question. Which only led to more questions!! See here: [Solspace Freeform custom fieldtype and notifcation templates](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/21968/solspace-freeform-custom-fieldtype-and-notifcation-templates)